# why "too good" is wrong?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

I have an example
"I love it here in NY. It's too good."
I know that it should be "very good" or "so good" but I don't know why "too good" is wrong.

Comment: It is really informal, but who said it is wrong? A phrase with a similar meaning might be "It's too good to be true", meaning it is beyond your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it is wrong - but it depends on what you mean to say.

> Too good

Means that it is "better than good".

On the entire good-scale, ranging from fairly good (1) to extremely good (100), "Too good" would be above the scale (100+).

Did that make sense?

Comment: **Too good** can have a negative sense.

Comment: Sure - depending on usage. `You are too good to me` as opposed to `Too good to be true`.

Answer (score 0):

"Too good" is not wrong.  It is a hyperbolic expression that means really really good.  However, you would use it conversationally or in creative or informal writing.  You should not use it in academic writing.

"Too good to be true" is an expression that means something shouldn't be trusted. It means that something is not as good as it seems and there must be hidden problems.